# Access value of a text field between view controllers in a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I created a tabbed application in Xcode using File > New > Project > Tabbed Application. I have two tabs named "First View" and "Second View".

In the storyboard for the "Second View" I drew a "Text Field" control.
How can I access the value of this text field from within FirstViewController's `viewDidLoad`?